# Pandas get mean value within relative time range by another value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I am working with a DataFrame with a `DatetimeIndex` and two additional columns, `A` and `B`, and trying to provide an output DataFrame to answer a question like:

> Determine the average value `B` for each `A` in months 6-12 after earliest occurrence of `A`

I have been working with `pd.Grouper` and understand how to group DateTime index in buckets (e.g. `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).mean()`), but am unclear as to how to compute the average over some period since the earliest observation for each value `A` in the dataset.

The input DataFrame looks something like:

```py
data = {
    'A': ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y'],
    'B': [10, 32, 12, 13, 24, 32, 12, 72, 90],
    'created_on': [
        '2018-01-31', 
        '2019-02-25', 
        '2018-02-12', 
        '2019-05-31', 
        '2021-03-12', 
        '2020-04-23', 
        '2016-01-11', 
        '2016-05-02', 
        '2018-12-31',
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['created_on']))
df.drop(['created_on'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

This generates a DataFrame like the following:

```
+------------+---+----+
| created_on | A | B  |
+------------+---+----+
| 2018-01-31 | x | 10 |
| 2019-02-25 | x | 32 |
| 2019-05-31 | x | 13 |
| 2021-03-12 | y | 24 |
| 2016-05-02 | y | 72 |
| ...        | . | .. |
+------------+---+----+
```

The target is a desired output shaped like:

```
+---+----------------------------------------------+
| A | avg_B_6_12_months_after_earliest_observation |
+---+----------------------------------------------+
| x |                                         12.2 |
| y |                                         18.1 |
+---+----------------------------------------------+
```

The values in the `avg_B_6_12_months_after_earliest_observation` column above are for example only, they do not correlate to the values provided in the example input DataFrame.

Comment: kindly add an example for how the average for `x` is computed

Comment: Can you elaborate more about each `A` in months 6-12? I don't understand how you got `12.2` and `18.1` for x and y

Comment: @Chris apologies, updated the question to clarify. The numbers I added are just to provide example values, they do not correlate to the example input specifically.

Comment: Alright, but still confused with the logic. You want the average of each item in `A`, excluding their first occurrence, as well as only those month are between 6 and 12?

Comment: @Chris For each `A` in the data, I'm looking for the average `B` between months 6 and 12 after the first observation of that `A` in the data.  Something like 'customer `A` spent an average of `B` over all of their orders placed in months 6-12 after they  placed their first order’ for each customer `A` in the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea is to use `groupby.transform` with `idxmin` to align per row the date of the first occurrence of each element in A. Then you can compare the index with the value of the first occurrence adding 6 or 12 months. Use this in a loc to select the wanted rows, `groupby` and `mean`.

```
# working dummy example
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'A': ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y'],
     'B': [10, 32, 12, 13, 24, 32, 12, 72, 90],},
    index = pd.to_datetime(
        ['2018-01-31', '2018-02-25', '2018-08-12', 
         '2018-10-31', '2021-03-12', '2016-10-23', 
         '2016-01-11', '2016-05-02', '2016-12-31'])
)
print(df)

# helper series with aligned index and idxmin per A
s = df.groupby(['A'])['B'].transform('idxmin')
print(s)
# 2018-01-31   2018-01-31
# 2018-02-25   2018-01-31 # here first date if x align with this row
# 2018-08-12   2018-01-31
# 2018-10-31   2018-01-31
# 2021-03-12   2016-01-11
# 2016-10-23   2016-01-11
# 2016-01-11   2016-01-11
# 2016-05-02   2016-01-11
# 2016-12-31   2016-01-11
# Name: B, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Now you can get the result

```
res = (
    # select rows with date in the 6-12 months after 1rst occurrence
    df.loc[(s.index>=s+pd.DateOffset(months=6)) 
          & (s.index<=s+pd.DateOffset(months=12))]
       # groupby and mean
      .groupby('A')['B'].mean()
      # cosmetic to fit expected output
      .rename('avg_B_6_12_months_after_earliest_observation')
      .reset_index()
)
print(res)
#    A  avg_B_6_12_months_after_earliest_observation
# 0  x                                          12.5
# 1  y                                          61.0
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can define a custom function and apply it to `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`:

```
def filtersum(data):
    data = data.iloc[1:]
    ind = data.index[data.index.month.to_series().between(6, 12)]
    return data.loc[ind, "B"].mean()

new_df = df.sort_index().groupby("A", as_index=False).apply(filtersum)
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
   A   NaN
0  x   NaN
1  y  90.0
```

Logic:

- `data.iloc[1:]`: Excludes the first observation from the calculation
- `data.index[data.index.to_series().between(6, 12)`]: filters the indices if their months are between 6 and 12 (inclusive).
- `df.sort_index().groupby`: data must be sorted by their indices so that excluded first observation is indeed the chronological first.

Note (based on the sample data):

Customer `x` didn't spend anything between June and December:

```
            A   B
created_on       
2018-01-31  x  10
2018-02-12  x  12
2019-02-25  x  32
2019-05-31  x  13
```

Customer `y` only spent once in `2018-12-31`:

```
            A   B
created_on       
2016-01-11  y  12
2016-05-02  y  72
2018-12-31  y  90 <<<
2020-04-23  y  32
2021-03-12  y  24
```